# How to move sidebar at Left to Right side in Brackets IDE. Is there any plugin available?

Tags: ide, adobe-brackets

How to move sidebar at Left to Right side in Brackets IDE. Is there any plugin available? Previously i used Geany IDE. So i need this option like in Geany IDE.

Comment: Was a solution to this found?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I know of to do this at the moment.

But it **is** in principle possible. When you press F12 in Brackets and inspect your sidebar you can move it to the right with css.
Someone has to sit down and re-position the editor with css if it's possible and make a theme / plugin.